# strpos($array,$check) in loop

Tags: php, while-loop, wildcard

I am using a While loop to go through the result of a sql Query. Inside of the While loop I am using a for loop to do a "wildcard search" in an array. Right now I am getting way to many results. The goal is to compare the rows in the `$social_result` from the SQL query with the content of the array `$email_rank_results` and add 1 to the `$social_cnt` variable if found. I would really appreciate if someone could give me some advise on how to change the code to achieve this.

The `$email_rank_results` array contains values like 'google.com','facebook.com','linkedin.com','twitter.com'

The `$social_result` contains values like 'pages.facebook.com', 'nb-linkedin.com', 'plus.google.com'

Here is my code:

```
$socialSQL= sprintf("SELECT name FROM class_social");
$social_result = mysql_query($socialSQL) or die ("Error in query: $socialSQL " . mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($social_result)) {
$check = $row[0];
$max = count($email_rank_results);
for($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++)
{

if (stripos($email_rank_results[1],$check) !== false)
{
    $social_cnt = $social_cnt+1;
}
}
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the code you have so far?

Comment: Why are you not limiting your query based on the search condition? Why do the "search" in PHP?

Comment: The problem with the code is that the I receive too many results. There is a logical error in the code, not a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

1. you mixed haystack with needle
2. in foreach loop you compare only first element of array $email_rank_results

replace:

```
stripos($email_rank_results[1], $check)
```

with

```
stripos($check,  $email_rank_results[$x]))
```

or simple use foreach loop

```
foreach($email_rank_results as $email_rank_result)
{

  if (stripos($check, $email_rank_result) !== false)
  {
    $social_cnt = $social_cnt+1;
  }
}
```

in above i assume that $email_rank_results is flat array, ie array('google.com', 'facebook.com');

Comment: ziollek, this did the trick. I was blinded by starring at the code for hours I guess